# Elf error: Request error: invalid ELF_C_* argument (when i try to run my programm)

Tags: c, unix, profiling, profiler

I  created a programm which obtains adreses of load/store operations to create a memory profile. It compiles fine. But, I am getting following error when I try to run it:

```
   Elf error: Request error: invalid ELF_C_* argument
    --FATAL-- #68: Dyninst was unable to create the specified process
    --FATAL-- #68: create process failed bootstrap
    profile: profile.c:27: void createProcess(const char*, const char**): 

Assertion `g_bpProcess' failed.
```

I am using Red Hat  system. With core 3.10.26. GCC 4.8.2.

I am installed boost 1.53. added it rath to PATH and to LD_LIBRARY_PATH,

installed libelf with `--prefix=/path/to/elf_bld/`

installed libwarf with `--enable-shared --prefix=/path/to/dwarf_bld/ and with export LIBS="-lelf", export LDFLAGS="-L/path/to/elf_bld/lib/" , CPPFLAGS="-I/path/to/elf_bld/include"`

installed DyninstAPI-8.1.1 with `--prefix=/path/to/Dyn_bld/ --with-boost=/path/to/boost_1_53_0/ --with-libelf=/path/to/elf_bld --with-libdwarf-incdir=/path/to/lobdwarf --with-libdwarf-libdir=/path/to/libdwarf`

Istallation was with not a root user.

I compile so

```
    CC    = g++
    CFLAGS    = -Wall -static
    EXECNAME= profile
    LIB    =    -L /path/to/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib  -L/path/to/Dyn_bld/lib -L /path/to/libdwarf -L /path/to/elf_bld/lib

    INCLUDE =    -I /path/to/boost_1_53_0/ -I /path/to/Dyn_bld/include/  -I /path/to/libdwarf/ -I /path/to/elf_bld/include/

    DYNINST_ROOT =/path/to/Dyn_bld/lib

    $(EXECNAME): $(EXECNAME).o
        $(CC) $(EXECNAME).o ${INCLUDE} ${LIB} \
            -ldyninstAPI -lsymtabAPI -lcommon -ldwarf -lelf -o $(EXECNAME)

    $(EXECNAME).o: ./$(EXECNAME).c
        $(CC) -g -c $(CFLAGS) $(EXECNAME).c

clean:
    @rm -f $(EXECNAME).o $(EXECNAME) core
```

and

```
export CC=gcc
export DYNINST_ROOT=/path/to/Dyn_bld
export DYNINSTAPI_RT_LIB=/path/to/Dyn_bld/lib/libdyninstAPI_RT.so.8.1.1
```

So, can anybody help me with this?

I am stuck at this really badly. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Dmitriy